# Generate random number with arc4random_uniform

Tags: ios, swift

I want to generate some random numbers (1 to limit) and store them with an array. Here's my codes:

```
var results = [Int]()
    for i in 0...qut
    {
        let lim = limit - 1
        results[i] = Int(arc4random_uniform(lim)) + 1
    }
```

And then xcode told me that "Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'UInt32'. "

So I made some changes:

```
results[i] = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(lim))) + 1
```

There's no error now. But when I run it, it report an error: "Fatal error: Index out of range."

Could someone tell me how can I fix that?

Comment: By the way, your example can generate repeating numbers. E.g. theoretically, this could generate the value `0` repeated `qut + 1` times. Is that OK? Or do you want to take some sequence of values and shuffle it in order to prevent repeated values?

Answer (score 1):

You can't add items to an array using subscripts. You need to use the array `append()` function:

```
results.append(Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(lim))) + 1)
```

And if you use the `map()` function it's much simpler:

```
let count = 10
let limit = 5
let results = (0...count).map { _ in Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(limit))) + 1 }
```

Comment: Better yet, you can just use `(0...qut).map{ Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(limit - 1))) + 1) }`.

Comment: @alexander: Well yeah, but you gotta crawl before you can walk, and higher order functions take a little getting used to. (Especially if you don't know what closures are.)

Comment: Yeah but I think it's worth mentioning. It simplifies code substantially, so I think it's beneficial for even new programmers to use. And really, having a function (heh) knowledge of `map` doesn't even require you know about closures. It's just a pair of `{`/`}`. It doesn't look much different than a `for` loop.